# Eclipse different behaviour for "Unchecked" warning due to "Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter". How to fix?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a simple `Entry` object for populating a list

```
public class Entry {
    //fields

    public Entry(int a, String b, String c) {
        //...
    }

    //some getters
}
```

and an `AsyncTask` that retrieves the entries.
On its `onProgressUpdate`...

```
                                               (here)
                                                 |
@Override                                        V
protected void onProgressUpdate(List<Entry>... param) {
    for (Entry e : param[0]) myAdapter.add(e);

    progressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have the warning:

> Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter param

This happens on a PC Linux 64bit while the **opposite** warning is shown on a notebook with the same version of Eclipse, same android project, same Linux Mint 16, just a 32bit OS, stating something as "*remove this unnecessary annotation*" (sorry if this is not the precise warning, I'm on the desktop PC now).

So basically I add and remove back and forth the annotation, switching between the two machines. I think this may be related, obviously, to the Java compiler in use or some other workspace setting.

Now, I'm not asking what *actually* is that setting/environment difference, but **my question is** if there is something that I can do in the code to fix this issue and remove the origin of the warning itself. I've read about the origin of this warning and what "heap pollution" means here, but no source gives a hint on a possible fix (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462079/potential-heap-pollution-via-varargs-parameter) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295635/how-to-fix-unchecked-call-warning-in-java))

**Edit**:
I noticed that another `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` sits on `doInBackground`, 
where I call

```
List<Entry> list;
//inside a for statement:
    publishProgress(list);
//repeated N times
```

that gives this warning:

> Type safety: A generic array of List is created for a varargs parameter