# Eclipse 32bit and 64bit different behavior handling a 9-patch (apparently)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-drawable, nine-patch

I found that building the same app on two different machines leads to a different behavior for Eclipse (or maybe the ADT plugin or whatever, this is why I'm asking) handling a 9-patch PNG.

I integrated the `PageProgressView` from the android stock browser (that thin progress bar for the tab loading) as progress bar for my own app.

This progress bar runs on the `actionBar`'s edge.
it uses this 9-patch drawable in its *mdpi*, *hdpi* and *xhdpi* variants: [image: 9p-dr]

- this is the intended appearance when the app is built on the 64bit desktop machine (here we have around 33% progress):

  [image]

while

- this is the wrong look when the same code is built and run on the same device (here the progress has gone around the 80%; the background is dark, but some artifacts are visible around the drawable):

  [image: img2]

Note: the Eclipse versions, although 32 and 64bit, are both updated to latest versions, as is the ADT plugins. OSs are both Linux Mint 16, obviously again 32 and 64 bit for laptop and desktop machines respectively.

Sure, for "production" I can use the desktop, but anyway, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Note-2: I already encountered a different behavior between the two machines, see: [**this SO q.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443493/eclipse-different-behaviour-for-unchecked-warning-due-to-potential-heap-pollu), but I'm not sure if the two issues are related.

Comment: Copy the graphics from your sdk/platforms folder.

Comment: For instance, `.../sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res/drawable-mdpi`

Comment: Thanks, but this progress drawable is not from the SDK but from the stock browser's res folder: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser

Comment: You have the source: change the resources in the source. (accidental word joke)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to sound rude, but if you read the Q., the project "as is" (pulled with GIT, "refreshed" and "cleaned" from Eplipse every time) works on a machine and not on another. What resource do I have to change?

Comment: now, THIS is rude... Anyway, the 9-patch you are referencing is different. Already checked (progress_primary_holo_dark.9.png).